# What gem bonus applies to socketed off-hand items?

Tags: diablo-iii

Gems provide 3 different bonuses depending on what they're inserted into: Helms, Weapons, and "Other". What do off-hand items like Wizard orbs, Demon Hunter quivers, and Witch Doctor mojos count as?

I'm leaning toward "other", but *technically* these items are equipped in weapon slots. Which is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Off-hands use "other" gem bonuses.

[image: gem]
[image: off-hand]

Answer (score 10):

Any off-hand items are not counted as weapons, thus they will the "other" bonus from gems.

[image: Off-hand Book]

Answer (score 2):

They count as "other".

I've tested this, and you definitely do not get the weapon bonus for shields, mojos, etc..